# Multiple lines are gets drawn with Graphics2D

Tags: java, swing, graphics, draw

I am trying to develop asmall application that draws geometrics shapes onto a image and saves them. I have this code in my panel class:

```
@Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if (getBufferedImage() != null)
        {
            g.drawImage(getBufferedImage(), 120, 0, getBufferedImage().getWidth(), getBufferedImage().getHeight(), null);
        }

        for (Shape s : getShapes())
        {
            if (getBufferedImage() != null)
            {
                Graphics2D graphics = getBufferedImage().createGraphics();
                s.draw(graphics);
            }
        }

    }
```

`getBufferedImage()` will return the bufferedImage of the loaded image. And `s.draw()` is the method in the respective shape classes that I have defined.

Like in Rectangle it has code: `graphics.drawRect()`
Line : `graphics.drawLine()`

Method in Line Class:

```
@Override
public void draw(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(getColor());

    g.drawLine(getXAxis(), getYAxis(), getWidth() + getXAxis(), getHeight() + getYAxis());
}
```

And these are my overridden methods of MouseAdapter

```
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)
{
    switch (getSelectedShape())
    {
        case Rectangle:
        {
            getShapes().add(new Rectangle(event.getX(), event.getY(), getSelectedColor(), isFilled()));
            break;
        }

        case Line:
        {
            getShapes().add(new Line(event.getX(), event.getY(), getSelectedColor()));
            break;
        }
    }

    repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event)
{
    if (event == null || event.getPoint() == null || getShapes().size() <= 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    Shape currentShape = getShapes().get(getShapes().size() - 1);

    if (currentShape == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    currentShape.mouseDragged(event.getPoint());

    repaint();
}
```

Now, when I draw any shape multiple shapes get drawn instead:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what code is there on `s.draw(g);` ? I hope you a are doing some calculation based on MouseListener, MouseMotionEvent.

Comment: Why do draw twice in the loop s.draw(graphics); and s.draw(g);

Comment: @shazin I have edit my question

Comment: @Beniton I have edited the question by providing the draw() method of Line class

Comment: @SaikiranGosikonda Can you also include the MouseListener related code. And how do you calculate the coordinates , height and width?

Comment: @SaikiranGosikonda ok i got the problem now. You need to override mouseReleased and should add the shape there instead of mousePressed. Let me know if you need more code help.

Comment: No, even though I have override mouseReleased instead of mousePressed. It is still same

Comment: *".. i will give you the code"* For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

I have some variables

```
private boolean start = false;
private ArrayList<Line> shapes = new ArrayList<Line>();
private Line currentLine = null;
```

Adding MouseHandlers

```
MouseHandler mouseHandler = new MouseHandler();
addMouseListener(mouseHandler);
addMouseMotionListener(mouseHandler);
```

The MouseHandler part.

```
private class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                start = true;
                currentLine = new Line();
                currentLine.setFirst(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));
                currentLine.setLast(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));
                shapes.add(currentLine);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                start = false;
                currentLine.setLast(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));
                currentLine = null;
                repaint();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if (start) {
                currentLine.setLast(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }
```

And the paint

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    for(Line line : shapes){
        g.drawLine(line.getFirst().x, line.getFirst().y, line.getLast().x, line.getLast().y);
    }
}
```

For save it to BufferedImage.

```
public void saveImage() throws IOException {
   BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
   Graphics2D graphics = image.createGraphics();
   graphics.setColor(Color.black);
   for (Line line : shapes) {
            graphics.drawLine(line.getFirst().x, line.getFirst().y, line.getLast().x, line.getLast().y);
   }
   graphics.dispose();
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("Beniton drawing.png"));
```

}

Add a button and call saveImage()

Comment: But, this code is also not working. And the code which I have given in the question is working fine if I don't have any image and I am drawing shapes on an empty panel. It is causing the issue only when I try to draw shapes on a BufferedImage

Comment: the code above is working fine. You just need to refine you code according to you requirement. The basics is same.

Comment: Is it working if you are trying to draw shape on a bufferedImage. Can you please tell me how you are drawing shapes on an image

Comment: I have not tried drawing  on a buffered image. But i am sure it would work. It is just acquiring the graphics and doing the drawing. So it should work.

Comment: Graphics2D graphics = getBufferedImage().createGraphics();
 shape.draw(graphics); And in the shape class I have the same code that you have given in the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114338/discussion-between-beniton-and-saikiran-gosikonda).

Comment: I have not seen the code that was mentioned in the saveImage() method. If I move the code that draws shapes on an image from paintComponent() to some other method like saveImage(). It is working fine. Thank you very much for your patience and help.

Answer (score 1):

Split the creation of the BufferedImage from the paint code.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g;
    for (Shape s : getShapes()) {
        graphics.draw(shape);
    }
}

public void saveAsImage()
{
    if (bufferedImage == null) {
        // Create bufferedImage
    }

    Graphics2D graphics = nufferedImage.createGraphics();
    paint(graphics);           
    graphics.dispose();
}
```

Of course you could also in paintComponent only draw the bufferedImage, and on adding a shape create a new bufferedImage, though that seems more inefficient, error prone (when layouting to other size).

Besides the needed `Graphics.dispose` the code does not obey *"paint fast without side-effect."*

Comment: But, where should I call this saveAsImage() method. If I call it in the paintComponent() method it is giving stockOverflowError

Comment: Where do you need the buffered image? If the list of shapes is sufficient, you could leave it out. If the buffered image was for smooth drawing, JPanel by default uses "double buffering" - swapping two buffers. So then a buffered image is not needed too.

Comment: Beniton gives the more suited answer I think.